# Sufficient Statistics, normal distribution

Tags: self-study, inference

Let X be a single observation from $N(0,\theta)$. $(\theta=\sigma^2)$

a)Is X a sufficient statistics?

b)Is |X| a sufficient statistics?

What I did

$$f(x;u,\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}e^{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{x}{\sqrt\theta})^2}I_{[-\infty,\infty]}(x)$$

So I can just say that $g(T(x),\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}e^{\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{x}{\sqrt\theta})^2}$ and $h(x)=1$?

I do not know why but in my head I can only think in $x^2$

How can I make the item b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) let $T(x) = x$. You can simply observe that $f(x|\theta) = f(T(x)|\theta)$ and so $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

For (b) let $T(x) = |x|$. Observe that $x^2$ = $|x|^2$ and the result should be clear.

For intuition on (b), note that if $\mu = 0$ then $\sum_i (x_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2$ so the signs of the individual $x_i$ don't matter with respect to the variance.

For both of these you can just use the factorization theorem (as opposed to exponential family results). Remember that what this says is that if $T(x)$ is a statistic then $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$ if $f(x|\theta) = g(T(x)|\theta) \times h(x)$. This means that if we can replace $x$ with $T(x)$ everywhere that it appears then by setting $h(x) = 1$ we have our result.

Edit:
For your part (b), the key thing to note is that $\exp{(-\frac{x^2}{2\theta})} = \exp{(-\frac{|x|^2}{2\theta})}$. From here it is straightforward to apply the factorization theorem.

Comment: More details please.

Comment: Could you give more details on what you've tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: The idea that I tried to use is that $T_2(x)=x$ and $T_1(x)=x^2=g(T_2)$ and $T_1$ is sufficient this implies that $T_2(x)=x$ is sufficient right?

Comment: If $T_1$ is sufficient for $\theta$ and $T_2 = g(T_1)$ then $T_2$ is only guaranteed to be sufficient if $g$ is 1-1. So in your case you have $g(x) = x^2$ which is not 1-1 so you don't have this guarantee. It worked out in this case but that's not a sound way to proceed. Try using the factorization theorem.

Comment: $x^2$ is sufficient too?

Comment: I think now I understand it, was looking at only for $x^2$

Comment: It really comes down to trying to either replace $x$'s with $T(x)$'s or separate them from $\theta$ and move the $x$'s into $h(x)$.